# MySQL database pattern for multilingual site – table with translations for each parent table or one for all?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

So I am creating Database design for a large, scalable application where multiple tables may appear in the future. I currently have about 30 tables that need translations. Due to this number I do not want to create tables by example: Products & Product Translations, just one table for all translations.

**First way (very time consuming in my case)**
Table `Products`

```
| ID | Status  | Sku     | Availability |
+====+=========+=========+==============+
| 1  | Enabled | 1-black | 50           |
```

Table `Products_translations`

```
| ID | Product_ID | Lang | is_default | Name | Description    |
+====+============+======+============+======+================+
| 1  | 1          | EN   | true       | Bike | Very nice bike |
```

etc.

**Second way (my preference)**
Table `Products`

```
| ID | Status  | Sku     | Availability |
+====+=========+=========+==============+
| 1  | Enabled | 1-black | 50           |
```

Table `translations`

```
| ID | Parent_table | Parent_id | Lang | is_default | Key         | Value         |
+====+==============+===========+======+============+=============+===============+
| 1  | product      | 1         | EN   | true       | Name        | Bike          |
| 2  | product      | 1         | EN   | true       | Description | Very niceike  |
```

**My questions**

- Is the second way very different from the accepted standards?
- Is it correct according to pattern standards?
- Is there a better way (considering the number of tables needed for translation)?

Comment: The second way seems more flexible, but I might have a row for each translatable field, rather than aggregating them (better for joins) — but before you go too far I'd advise thinking about where the translations are coming from and how they will be input. The workflow for creating and maintaining the translations may put more constraints on your design that delivering the translated text at runtime. Edit to add: In fact, looking at the design, I don't think you need the `translation_fields` column at all. You can get that by querying keys in the `translations` table.

Comment: @Jerry Any suggestions how can I make it better? I came up with idea to create two tables for translations – `translations` and `translations_config`. In `translations` there will be what I have written above, and in `translations_config` will be settings like what fields are required to have translations in each table e.g. `products` or `posts`.

Comment: It depends so much on the way the translations will be maintained that I really can't guess. Are you going to have a UI for the translators? Will they deliver a spreadsheet or text file? Will an engineer be required to import the data every time there's a new phrase or an edit to an old one? I've seen more than one system that keeps translations in flat files that translators maintain directly.

Comment: @Jerry, i will have for example three tables: `products`, `translations` and `translations_config`. In last table there will be info about what fields are required in translation and which are optional. In admin’s panel there will be subsection in each form with translations, and here will be shown what fields are required and optional (from translations config)

Comment: Besides what was said here, do you see any practise that matches my needs and is accepted pattern/standard? There will be other people working on that project.

Comment: I've seen a couple of projects (where volunteers supplied translations), where the translation table was an external file that the translator could maintain. That is (or at least was) how MacOS handled localization.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with that idea:

to create two tables:
`translations`

```
| ID | Parent_table | Parent_id | Lang | is_default | Key         | Value         |
+====+==============+===========+======+============+=============+===============+
| 1  | products     | 1         | EN   | true       | Name        | Bike          |
| 2  | products     | 1         | EN   | true       | Description | Very niceike  |
```

`translations_config`

```
| ID | table    | required_translations   | optional_translations |
+====+==========+=========================+=======================+
| 1  | products | ["name", "description"] | ["attributes"]        |
```

`translations_config` is needed to create translations from ACP.

and regular table eg. `products`

```
| ID | Status  | Sku     | Availability |
+====+=========+=========+==============+
| 1  | Enabled | 1-black | 50           |
```

and `SELECT` will look similar to:

```
SELECT 
    products.id, translations.lang, translations.is_default, translations.key, translations.value
FROM 
    products
    INNER JOIN 
        translations ON (translations.parent_id = products.id AND translations.parent_table = 'products')
```

But I don't know if it is accepted standard and will be readable for future engineers working on that project.